# upload photo from iPhone to Windows IIS/PHP5.6

Tags: php, ios, iphone, iis, upload

Simple upload script, works fine from a PC, but when I try and upload a photo from an iPhone, the page just halts, like it's trying to load, and nothing happens.

This is my HTML:

```
<form name="uploadImageForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="newImage" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submitNewImage" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

This is my PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitNewImage'])) {

    $userPicDirectory = 'pics/' . $winUsername . '/';

    if(!file_exists($userPicDirectory) || !is_dir($userPicDirectory)){
        mkdir("pics/" . $winUsername . "/",0755);
    }

if ($_FILES['newImage']['error'] == 1) {

  $errorMsg = '<span style="color:red;">File size is too large.  File must be under 10MB.</span>';

} else if ($_FILES['newImage']['size'] == 0 || $_FILES['newImage']['name'] == '')    {

  $errorMsg = '<span style="color:red;">Please select a file.</span>';

} else {/////file was present, proceed

$allowed =  array('gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'GIF', 'PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG');

$filename = $_FILES['newImage']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
  $errorMsg = '<span style="color:red;">Only image files are allowed.</span>';
} else {///end file extension check, move on...

    $fileBasename = basename($_FILES['newImage']['name']);////this goes in DB
    $uploadfile = $userPicDirectory . basename($_FILES['newImage']['name']);

    $thefile = $_FILES['newImage']['tmp_name'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($thefile, $uploadfile)){//upload file


    $sqlUpdateImage = $db_con1->prepare("UPDATE user_info SET image_name=:image_name WHERE username=:username");
    $sqlUpdateImage->execute(array(':image_name' => $fileBasename, ':username' => $winUsername));

        header('Location: ' . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    }
}
}
}////end check if submit
```

In php.ini, upload_file_size is set to 10M.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing this over wifi or 3G/4G?

Comment: wifi, this is an internal web server, no public access.